# tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: xxx: undefined symbol: __cudaPushCallConfiguration

Tags: python, tensorflow, ubuntu

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 58, in <module>
    MODEL = importlib.import_module(FLAGS.model)  # import network module
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/my_asnl/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/root/autodl-tmp/my-pointASNL/models/pointasnl_cls.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pointnet_util import pointnet_sa_module
  File "/root/autodl-tmp/my-pointASNL/utils/pointnet_util.py", line 15, in <module>
    from tf_sampling import farthest_point_sample, gather_point
  File "/root/autodl-tmp/my-pointASNL/tf_ops/sampling/tf_sampling.py", line 13, in <module>
    sampling_module = tf.load_op_library(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'tf_sampling_so.so'))
  File "/root/miniconda3/envs/my_asnl/lib/python3.6/site-    packages/tensorflow/python/framework/load_library.py", line 61, in load_op_library
    lib_handle = py_tf.TF_LoadLibrary(library_filename)
```

**tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /root/autodl-tmp/my-pointASNL/tf_ops/sampling/tf_sampling_so.so: undefined symbol: __cudaPushCallConfiguration**

In the PointASNL model, when I compiled some files and then ran train.py, the above problem occurred.My TensorFlow is 1.13.1.How to solve the above problems?`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.